# Nvidia driver not working on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel

Nvidia drivers not working

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off Secure Boot in the BIOS, and now it works